# CAS Overlay 5.0 redirection after logout

Tags: cas

Using CAS Overlay 5.0 Spring Boot CAS Authentication Server. Wanted to know how to configure redirection after logout. I am using spring security CAS client

Comment: At Client side i have used the following configuration logout().logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").
                     
                        logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8080/cas/logout?service=http://localhost:9090").permitAll();

Comment: Logout is working but redirection is not working

Comment: You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55529612/9381897).

Answer (score 0):

Add this setting to `etc/cas/config/cas.properties` file:

```
cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=true
```