# Unable to redirect to Spring application page after logout from CAS Server

Tags: spring, security, server, cas, single-logout

I'm trying singleLogout from Spring boot application using CAS server.I'm able to logout from Spring application and CAS server but I want to redirect to my custom logout page of spring application *https://applicationip:port/application/logoutsuccesspage* rather than CAS logout page i.e. *https://casserverip:port/cas/logout*

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is your friend.

Quoting from official docs:

> Per the CAS Protocol, the /logout endpoint is responsible for
>   destroying the current SSO session. Upon logout, it may also be
>   desirable to redirect back to a service. This is controlled via
>   specifying the redirect link via the service parameter. The specified
>   service must be registered in the service registry of CAS and enabled
>   and CAS must be allowed to follow service redirects.

and related application properties:

```
# cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=false
# cas.logout.redirectParameter=service
# cas.logout.redirectUrl=https://www.github.com
# cas.logout.confirmLogout=false
# cas.logout.removeDescendantTickets=false
```

So first, you have to instruct cas to follow logout redirects by setting:

`cas.logout.followServiceRedirects=true`

and then provide the url that you wish to redirect users after logout:

`cas.logout.redirectUrl=https://applicationip:port/application/logoutsuccesspage`

References: [Logout - Single Logout](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Logout-Single-Signout.html#cas-logout) & [CAS Properties](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#logout)

**Note:** Docs refer to 5.3.x branch.